# Elementwise "between" of one pandas series containing the value and two series containing the lower/upper limits

Tags: python, pandas

I have three `Series`

```py
trans = pd.Series([2020-01-01, 2022-03-15 ...]) #transaction
start = pd.Series([2020-02-03, 2021-05-13]) #valid dates start
end =pd.Series([2020-02-28,2021-06-13]) #valid dates end
```

and I want to see if a transaction is "valid" which it is, if it was made in a date-range defined by `start` and `end` i.e `start[i]` and `end[i]` composes one date-range of which the transaction could be valid, e.g for the first transaction, I want to check if `2020-01-01` is between `(2020-02-03,2020-02-28)` or `(2021-05-13,2021-06-13)`.

I have tried using `between` e.g `trans.between(start,end)` but since `trans` is not the same size, it cannot be done in that way.

I have written a list comprehension but it loops through all `start`,`end` pairs for each element in `trans`, which is not optimal, since it should terminate when it just finds one pair.

I can remove some of the transactions by checking, if the date is above `min(start)` and below `max(end)`, but it still takes a while by my own solution

Comment: do you want to stop checking in `trans` if there is one match in `start-end` or do you want to check every single `trans` element but if it finds one match in `start-end` then don't look for more pairs in `start-end`?

Comment: The latter one i.e check all trans

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy broadcasting for test all values between all values of both `Series` and test if at least one value match in `any`:

```
ser = trans.to_numpy()[:, None]
left = start.to_numpy()
right = end.to_numpy()
m = ((left <= ser) & (ser <= right)).any(axis=1)

out = trans[m]
print (out)
```

Comment: It is indeed faster, but I assume it still checks *all* rows ?

Comment: @CutePoison - Yes, it test all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Hope it helps:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


trans = pd.Series(["2020-01-01", "2022-03-15", "2021-05-20", "2022-02-10", "2009-09-09"])
start = pd.Series(["2020-02-03", "2021-05-13", "2020-05-06"])
end =pd.Series(["2020-02-28","2021-06-13", "2020-05-08"])
                  
start = list(map(datetime.date.fromisoformat, start))
end = list(map(datetime.date.fromisoformat, end))
trans = list(map(datetime.date.fromisoformat, trans))

for elem in trans:
    print(elem)
    for lft,rgt in zip(start,end):
        if lft <= elem <= rgt:
            print(f'{elem} is between {lft} & {rgt}')
            break
```

output:

```
2020-01-01
2022-03-15
2021-05-20
2021-05-20 is between 2021-05-13 & 2021-06-13
2022-02-10
2009-09-09
```

it checks all elements but stops looking in start/end when finding a match